# Delete an item from hierarchical Collection

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a `city` from an `ObservationCollection<City>.`

**What I have tried:**

```
private static void DeleteCity(List<City> cities, City cityToDelete)
{
    City nodeToDelete = null;

    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        if (city.permanentId == cityToDelete.permanentId)
        {
            nodeToDelete = city;
            break;
        }
        DeleteCity(city.Children.ToList(), cityToDelete);
    }
    if (nodeToDelete != null)
    {
        cities.Remove(nodeToDelete);
        return;
    }
}

public static void SomeFunction(...................)
{
    ......
    ......
    ......

    DeleteCity(ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities.ToList(), cityToMove);

    ....
    ....
```

}

When I keep a breakpoint on `return;` in `DeleteCity` method. I can see that the passed in value for cityToDelete is deleted from cities. But when I go further to the caller function, I can see that ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities is still holding that particular city. Why it does not delete the city from that collection?

Comment: you seem to be passing in the city you want to move..

Comment: What does your DeleteCity(...,...) method do?

Comment: @kirsteng I am sure I am passing the correct city.

Comment: ServiceLocator.Instance.Cities isn't the collection you are passing into the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ServiceLocator` has the city that you deleted from the list because you called `ToList()`, which forces copying of the original data into a new list. Deleting an entry from a copy has no effect on the original list, explaining the behavior that you see.

Moreover, when you call the method recursively, you also make a copy by calling `ToList()` on the `Children` property. Therefore, the deletion is done from a copy of the list, not from the original. The original collection stays unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works like a charm. I will accept the answer after 7 minutes as per the rules of stackOverFlow.